# Is the relative velocity between these two particles increasing or decreasing?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

The displacement time equations of two particles are:
$$s_1 = 2t-4t^2$$
$$s_2 = -2t + 4t^2$$

By differentiating we can find $v_1,v_2$. Subtracting them gives: $v_1-v_2 = 4-16t$
Clearly, this continuously decreases with time, so the relative velocity decreases. But if we subtract $v_2 - v_1$, this increases with time ($16t-4$). It seems so simple and thus silly, but yet it's confusing me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you'll choose speed axis $x$, then relative velocity will tend to negative or positive axis side, but absolute value of speed difference will increase either way.

Answer (score 2):

Velocity is a vector. It has a direction.

You don't really see the direction here because it is a $1$D problem. But the sign indicates whether the direction is toward negative numbers (left) or positive (right).

Relative velocity is the velocity you would see if you sat on one particle and watched the other. $v_1 - v_2$ is the velocity of particle $1$ if you sat on particle $2$. $v_2 - v_1$ is the velocity of particle $2$ if you sat on particle $1$. These have the same magnitude, but opposite direction.

The magnitude indicates relative speed. When the magnitude is $0$, they are not moving with respect to each other. When the magnitude is decreasing, they are approaching the same speed, or slowing with respect to each other. When the magnitude increases, the relative speed is increasing.

Comment: My confusion *is* that they have opposite direction-one is increasing and the other is decreasing. If I take the modulus then it decreases till $t = 0.25$ and then increases. Is that the answer, or am I still missing something?

Comment: That is the answer. Sign indicates direction. Magnitude indicates relative speed. The relative speed decreases till $t = 0.25$ sec, and then increases.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is the difference between velocity and speed. If the problem is asking for speed, it is asking for the magnitude. If it is asking for velocity, it is asking for a vector. To ask whether a vector is decreasing or increasing would be to ask if its size is decreasing or increasing.